# image cache issue on nginx server

Tags: apache, nginx, reverse-proxy

nginx is delivering images and apache is our web server.
when requesting image below are response headers.

```
Accept-Ranges:bytes
Cache-Control:max-age=315360000
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:13780
Content-Type:image/jpeg
Date:Thu, 16 Nov 2017 11:44:58 GMT
ETag:"5a0d71ed-35d4"
Expires:Thu, 31 Dec 2037 23:55:55 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=60
Last-Modified:Thu, 16 Nov 2017 11:09:33 GMT
Server:nginx
```

we resize image on server with the same image name from php.
when we call http://example.domain.com/imagename.jpg?d=1 or http://example.domain.com/imagename.jpg?d=2 result is same old image upto 60 seconds.afterwords it shows new image on both above links.

it looks like nginx server cache issue.

**UPDATE**

It is due to open file cache setting ([open_file_cache](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#open_file_cache)) in nginx.conf
Currently resolved by below setting

```
open_file_cache off
```

Although i keep this question open, as i don't understand that how nginx ignore query string to image while returning that image from cache.

Comment: Try purging cache of cloudflare if you're using it

Comment: Do you have file cache turned on?

Comment: not using cloudflare. any specific setting to look for file cache?